# cx_freeze fatal error after InnoSetup

Tags: python, pygame, inno-setup, importerror, cx-freeze

I am trying to create a standalone executable with the help of cx_freeze and InnoSetup.
It's a very simple Python script that uses Pygame to create a graphical interface for a timer program.

I am able to run the script directly with python.exe with no problems. I am also able to compile the script into an executable with cx_freeze, and run it with no problems as well.

The problem arises after I used InnoSetup to create a single standalone executable. The program would not run and would display this message when I try to run it:

[image]

Would anyone with previous experience with this problem kindly help me out :)?

Facts:
- I'm using Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit
- I'm using Python 3.2.3 64-bit with Pygame 1.9.2
- I set cx_freeze not to create zip folders when compiling because it would cause    zipimporter error.

Thanks! If there's any other information that I should be providing, please let me know :D

Comment: I don't know what the `cx_freeze` or your Python script does, but I'd like to know many files does the `cx_freeze` have ? Are all of them extracted somewhere during installation ? I mean, if the `cx_freeze` or your script isn't missing some library or some another file ?

Comment: Compiling the script with cx_freeze creates 48 files in a single folder (including the executable). I don't think any libraries are missing because the error only occurs after using InnoSetup. The executable that cx_freeze created runs perfectly. Does that explain anything D:?

Comment: Well, *after using InnoSetup* is quite large term. So, you have installed all those files using InnoSetup in a certain directory. Are you running that from InnoSetup ? If so, what privileges does the installer have (did it ask for administrator elevation) ? Please use `@` when you want to notify someone by a comment (I don't have to since you're receiving all notifications because the question is yours). And anyway, welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Thanks @TLama! Sorry I wasn't being very specific because I'm not too familiar with InnoSetup. Yes, I built an installer for my program using InnoSetup. I then installed my program under a new directory (with admin privilege because it asked for elevation). It was only when running the executable that the installer (that InnoSetup made) created, the error code popped up. I also tried running the .exe with admin privilege, the error code still popped up. Thank you so much for your help! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Sorry, but I'm afraid I won't be able to help. You're compiling that script into an executable during installation process somehow or you have ready made one only included in the installer ? Sorry for my dumb question, but I really don't know Python.

Comment: @TLama: `cx_Freeze` is responsible for making an executable for the script, and he says it works after that step. Then he's using InnoSetup to make an installer from that.

Answer (score 1):

Does it work after installation when you simply run the installed files directly from a folder window?  ie. does it fail only when run at the end of the installer itself or via a created shortcut?

If so, then you probably have some dependency on the current working directory, and you will need to either fix that or set the `WorkingDir` parameter appropriately.

If it fails when you run it directly as well, then you are probably failing to install (or check for) some required dependency -- for example, Python itself.